# Jquery hover on elements with children

Tags: jquery, hover

I have this code:

```
<div class"classNameFather">
    <div class="className">
        <div class="className">
             <div.... (unlimited elements)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$('.className').hover(function() {
    //do hover stuff
}, function() {
    //do mouseout stuff
});

$('.classNameFather').hover(function() {
    //do hover stuff
}, function() {
    //do mouseout stuff
});
```

So what I'm trying to do is when i'm hover the last element or second or third... all the parents are not hover....

Only the first element has a diferent class name and there is no limit for children....

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop the event from bubbling up..

```
$('.className').hover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //do hover stuff
}, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //do mouseout stuff
});

$('.classNameFather').hover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //do hover stuff
}, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //do mouseout stuff
});
```

---

**Update**

Depending on the actual effect you want to accomplish, you might need to use the `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` methods instead of `.hover()` which uses (*`.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`*).

The difference can be seen in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Zse5V/